# Efficient loop over a integer range in Python

Tags: python, performance

I want to search for positions inside a range of integers. How to improve the code in terms of efficiency, since both my search list and the ranges are very big:

```
#Range list with ids
range_lst = [(121000, 122000, 'foo'), (123456, 124557, 'bar'), (156789, 163659, 'egg')]
# Positions which we want to scan
pos = [123456, 369369]
# Neighbouring windows size
window_size = 10000

for p in pos:
    for r in range_lst:
        range_area = range(r[0], r[1])
        range_area_window = range(r[0]-window_size, r[1]+window_size)
        id = r[2]
        if p in range_area:
            print (p, id, 'exact hit!')
        else:
            # If we don't find an exact hit, we check the neighbouring region +- 10000
            if p in range_area_window:
                print (p, id, 'neighbour hit!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that having a `range` is not necessary here. If you're only comparing against integer ranges, simple \$ \le \$ and \$ \ge \$ comparisons should suffice.

So, the following function is essentially the same:

```
def search_position(ranges, positions, window_size=10000):
    for low, high, range_id in ranges:
        for pos in positions:
            if low <= pos < high:
                print(pos, range_id, 'exact hit!')
            elif (low - window_size) <= pos < (high + window_size):
                print(pos, range_id, 'neighbour hit!')
```